# Primefaces selectOneMenu does not execute on change

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am writing a PrimeFaces application.  I have the following code in my XHTML:

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{lottoCheckerBean.selectedPowerBallDrawingDate}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawingDates}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I am expecting the following code to be executed in my `LottoCheckerBean` when a value is selected:

```
public void setSelectedPowerBallDrawingDate(String selectedPowerBallDrawingDate) {
    //get drawing
    PowerBallDrawing currentDrawing = null;
    for (int d = 0; d < powerBallDrawings.size(); d++) {
        if (powerBallDrawings.get(d).getDrawingDate().equals(selectedPowerBallDrawingDate)) {
            currentDrawing = powerBallDrawings.get(d);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (currentDrawing == null) {
        try {
            //create new drawing;
            currentDrawing = new PowerBallDrawing(selectedPowerBallDrawingDate);
            powerBallDrawings.add(currentDrawing);
            Arrays.sort(powerBallDrawings.toArray());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //will not happen so ignore
        }
    }
    this.selectedPowerBallDrawingDate = selectedPowerBallDrawingDate;
}
```

However, if I set a breakpoint at the beginning of the above method, the breakpoint is not reached.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you expect to execute upon *change* will be called when you *submit* the form in which your `selectOneMenu` is placed. That is when the value from the `selectOneMenu` will be passed to your bean.

If you would want to perform something upon any other event, such as *change*, you need to enable **ajax**:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{lottoCheckerBean.selectedPowerBallDrawingDate}"  >
    <f:selectItems value="#{lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawingDates}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{lottoCheckerBean.someMethod}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

When value is changed in the backing bean, `someMethod()` will be called.

I would recommend you to use `setSelectedPowerBallDrawingDate(String selectedPowerBallDrawingDate)` only as a setter which sets the value, not to conatain any business logic at all. Then let the method you call from `<p:ajax/>` do the business logic.

Comment: My only addition is that OP can explicitly submit the form synchronously by adding `onchange="submit()"` attribute to his `<p:selectOneMenu>` tag. +1

Comment: Yeah. But perhaps he would rather just submit a smaller part of the form (i.e. the selectOneMenu), the ajax way. Would result in less data passed. I would prefer using the `p:ajax` tag.